# 2 classes and one MainApp

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I have done the assignment as best as I could but I am still stuck. Apparently, some things are not okay with the code. Could someone please give me advice about what might be wrong with it? It works fine up until some point, but then I am not able to print out the details of the *Course* using the `toString()` method along with the details of the schedule, also using the `toString()` method.

```
//package declaration
package assignment2app;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment2App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Schedule s1=new Schedule();
        String r=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
              "Please enter the semester",
              "Information", 
              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        s1.setSemester(r);

        String t=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
              "Please enter the year",
              "Information", 
              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        int g=Integer.parseInt(t);
        s1.setYear(g);

        String u=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
              "Please enter the number of courses taken",
              "Information", 
              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        int w=Integer.parseInt(u);

        while(w!=0){ 
              String y=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                   "Please list the courses you have taken.Enter 'none' when you are done",
                   "Information", 
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
              Course c2=new Course(y, 3);
              if(!y.equalsIgnoreCase("none"))
                   s1.AddCourse(c2);
              else
                   w=0;
        }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s1.toString() ,
          "Schedule",
          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  if(w>5){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry you cannot take more than 5 courses", 
            "Information", 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }
  while(w>5){
       String j=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the name of the course that you would like to remove",
          "Information",
          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          s1.RemoveCourse(j);
       w--;   
   }

  Schedule s2=new Schedule();
  s2.setSemester("Summer1");
  s2.setYear(2014);
  int count=0;
  while(count<3){

  String f=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Course Code",
         "Data Entry",
         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  String h=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter the Course Credits", 
         "Data Entry", 
         JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  int j=Integer.parseInt(h);
  Course c1=new Course(f, j);
  s2.AddCourse(c1);
  count++;
  }
    }
}
```

The class Course is OK, I don't think there is anything wrong with it at all...

```
package assignment2app;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Course {
    private String code;
    private int credits;

  public Course(String a, int b){
      setCode(a);
      setCredits(b);
  }

    void setCode(String c){
        code=c;
    }

    String getCode(){
        return code;
     }

    void setCredits(int cr){
        credits=cr;
    }

    int getCredits(){
        return credits;
     }


    @Override
   public String toString(){
        return code+ " "+ credits;
    }
}
```

However, in Class Schedule, I am supposed to take a list of courses as a parameter in the method AddCourses. I think I haven't done that right.And I think I have created unnecessary ArrayLists in writing methods which I think will not help me to integrate all the information into a single ArrayList. So I would like to know about alternative ways I can do that. I am also supposed to know how to add a course into a schedule using input from the user in the main class. I have no idea how to do that...so would greatly appreciate some help.

```
package assignment2app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Schedule {
    private String semester;
    private int year;
    private ArrayList <String> CourseList; 

   public Schedule(){
       semester="none";
        year=2000;
       CourseList=new ArrayList <String> ();
   }

   ArrayList <String> c=new ArrayList<String>();
   public Schedule(String a, int b, ArrayList <String> c){
       semester=a;
        year=b;
       CourseList=c;
   }

   String getSemester(){
       return semester;
   }

   int getYear(){
       return year;
   }

   void setSemester(String s){
       if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("fall"))
           semester="Fall";
       else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Spring"))
           semester="Spring";
       else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Summer1"))
           semester="Summer1";
       else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Summer2"))
           semester="Summer2";
       else{
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                   "Invalid entry. Please enter one of the following: Fall/Spring/Summer1/Summer2", 
                   "Semester Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       }
   }

  void setYear(int y){
     if(y<2000 || y>2020)
     {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid year",
             "Information Prompt",
             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     }
     else if (y>=2000 || y<=2020)
         year=y;


}

  ArrayList <String> AddCourses(){
    ArrayList <String> w=new ArrayList <String>();
    w.addAll(CourseList);
    return w;
  }

  void AddCourse(Course d){
      ArrayList <Course> r=new ArrayList<Course>();
      r.add(d);

  }

   void RemoveCourses(){
       CourseList.clear();
   }

   void RemoveCourse(String d){
       CourseList.remove(d);
   }

   void coursesCount(){
       CourseList.size();
   }

   int totalCredits(){
    int s=CourseList.size()*3;
     return s;
   }

   ArrayList <String> coursesList(){
    ArrayList<String> w=new ArrayList<String>();
    w.addAll(CourseList);
    return w;
   }

    @Override
   public String toString(){
       return semester+" "+year+" "+CourseList;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have

```
private ArrayList <Course> CourseList;
```

which you are initializing in your constructor, so in your

```
void AddCourse(Course d){
```

just add individual course into courseList rather than create new arraylist every time.

Comment: When I do that it gives me an error saying that no suitable method found for AddCourse... It also says arguments in the lists differ. What do I do to correct that?

Comment: I changed the type of the array lists everywhere to course and it has solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

First thing to store your Courses in the final class it should be an arrayList of Courses not of Strings like:

```
private ArrayList<Course> CourseList;
CourseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

Next up I think you're asking for adding and removing Courses from your CourseList. You do this by two simple methods:

```
public void AddCourse(Course c2) {
    CourseList.add(c2);

}

public void removeCourse(Course c2) {
    CourseList.remove(c2);

}
```

In your other class you are asking for a course code to remove that course.

You can do this like this:

```
public void RemoveCourse(String j) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < CourseList.size(); i++){
        if(CourseList.get(i).getCode().equals(j)){
            removeCourse(CourseList.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This method searches through your courselist until it finds one where the coursecode is the same as you specified and then it removes it.

For the input for the user you could use a scanner like this:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Please enter user class code : ");
 String code = in.nextLine();      
 System.out.println("Please enter your credits: ");
 String cred= in.nextLine();    
 addCourse(new Course(code, Integer.parseInt(cred)))
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Add three courses to schedule2 using the method addcourse. You will (1) ask the user to enter the details for each course, (2) create an object of type course using the input values, (3) add the course to the schedule.

Comment: This is what I have to do in the last part... I don't think that code will work well with the description. I think this part of the assignment is quite abstract

Comment: I still don't know how to use the toString to list the details in class course with those in class schedule, also using the toSting method...

Comment: Method toString which return the schedule; semester, year, number of credits, number of courses, and the list of all courses as a string.